# Microsoft Management Console in .NET applications

Tags: .net, mmc

1. Is it possible to host MMC snap-ins inside a .NET application?
2. If not, is it possible to launch MMC with the "Computer Management" snap-in set to an arbitrary computer name

Answer (score 1):

You should start poking around with the [MMC 3.0 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692755.aspx).